# BASH Script : Explode string and save to file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, awk, command-line-interface

I need some help. I have this

**info.txt**

```
[test.local]
user=test
group=test
;
[game.local]
user=game
group=game
;
```

this is my objective, i want it to be separated with **;** and put it in a file where the file name is based on the value of **[ ]**

like this

**test.local.txt**

```
[test.local]
user=test
group=test
```

**game.local.txt**

```
[game.local]
user=game
group=game
```

and here my code currently **files.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<info.txt)

SAVEIFS=$IFS   
IFS=$';'     
val=($value) 
IFS=$SAVEIFS  

for (( i=0; i<${#val[@]}; i++ ))
do
  echo "${val[$i]}"
done
```

in which im stuck with array only, how can i achieve it.

Comment: And what's your concrete question? Which code did you write to achieve this?

Comment: @user1934428 hi sir, already updated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-awk` command:

```
awk -v RS=';\n' 'NF{f=$1; gsub(/[][]/, "", f); printf "%s", $0 > (f ".txt")}' info.txt
```

**Details:**

- `-v RS=';\n'`: sets input record separator to `;` followed by newline
- `NF{...}`: Execute only for non-empty lines
- `f=$1`: Save `$1` which is `[...]` line in variable `f`
- `gsub(/[][]/, "", f)`: Removes `[` and `]` from variable `f`
- `printf`: Redirects a single block to a filename made with value of `f` and text `".txt"`

Comment: thanks sir . this is working. can you give me details on what is happening about this command with its options, what does it mean.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I added explanation in answer.

Comment: sir. how can i add a path on the files created

Comment: Yes definite you can add. Just add it before f after redirect >

Comment: hi sir. it was change [test.local] and [game.local] will not be included in the txt file, and the rest is same.

Comment: Can you paste command you're using. I am away from computer will come back in an hour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197533/discussion-between-rkevx21-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 fn=$(echo "${val[$i]}"|head -n 1| tr -d '[]').txt
```

to find the name of the file to create and

```
 echo "${val[$i]}"|tail -n +2
```

to produce the content of the file.